# Python random number excluding one variable

Tags: python, variables, random

Is it possible to create a variable with a random number except for one number that is stored in a variable?

For example:

```
import random
x = raw_input("Number: ")
y = random.randint(1,6)
```

So the variable `x` could never be `y`

Comment: There's no built-in `random.except`, but you could easily create it - one option is just to loop until `x != y`.

Comment: Is `x` always an integer between 1 and 6?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
import random

x = int(raw_input("Number(1-6): ")) # note I made x an int

while True:
    y = random.randint(1, 6)
    if x != y: break
```

Comment: No, you don't want to use `input` with Python 2. `input` will evaluate the entered data and [eval really is dangerous](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html).

Comment: @Matthias Right you are

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest you to use [random.choice](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.choice) form the list of numbers sans your number of choice

```
import random
x = raw_input("Number: ")
y = random.choice(range(1, x) + range(x+1, 6))
```

Comment: As long as there are just 6 numbers this solution will be fine.

Answer (score 4):

Rather than use `random.randint()`, produce a list of possible values and remove the one you don't want. Then use `random.choice()` on the reduced list:

```
import random
x = int(input("Number: "))
numbers = list(range(1, 7))
numbers.remove(x)
y = random.choice(numbers)
```

Demo:

```
>>> import random
>>> x = 5
>>> numbers = list(range(1, 7))
>>> numbers
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
>>> numbers.remove(x)
>>> numbers
[1, 2, 3, 4, 6]
>>> random.choice(numbers)
6
>>> random.choice(numbers)
1
>>> random.choice(numbers)
2
```

Comment: If range will be thousand would it be inefficient to create a list to contain all?

Comment: @alper 1000 elements is not that many, I’d worry when you have 100 times that many. It all depends on how much you need to remove and how often you need to generate a number; the higher the chance you’d pick the exception, the more efficient it is to *not* have the exception in the input to `random`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure X will be a number between 1 and 6, you can choose from range excluding X.

```
import random
x = input("Number: ")
end  = 6
r = range(1,x) + range(x+1, end)
random.choice(r)
```

Comment: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'range' and 'range'

Comment: @WalidBousseta this is a pretty old answer.python2 supported this operation because `range` returned lists. In py3, you'd have to to `list(range(...)) + list(range(...))` explicitly

Answer (score 0):

In python 3 to skip idx 11 from 0..20

```
import numpy as np
range = np.concatenate([np.arange(0, 10, dtype=np.int), np.arange(11, 20, dtype=np.int)])
choice = np.random.choice(range)
```

Answer (score -1):

As [@jonrsharpe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29804599/python-random-number-excluding-one-variable#comment47736958_29804599) mentioned in the comments of your question, a simple while-loop would be the easiest way to achieve this:

```
import random
x = int(raw_input("Number: "))
y = random.randint(1,6)

while x == y:
    y=random.randint(1,6)
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `while x == y`?  As written, it's going to loop until `random.randint(1, 6)` returns `y`.

Comment: @DougR. Edited. I made an edit to the question before the grace period was over and I forget to re-check if it works lol.