# Random number in python

Tags: python

I want to print random number using python. if I use random.randint(1, 10) it would give me random number from 1-10. what if I want to print random number between 1-10 but number 2 is not include? thankyou

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Generate 'n' unique random numbers within a range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22842289/generate-n-unique-random-numbers-within-a-range)

Comment: Does this answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29804599/python-random-number-excluding-one-variable

Answer (score 5):

You can use `random.choice`:

```
print(random.choice([1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]))
```